# Rails remote and jquery ajaxStop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Rails 5.2 and gems 'jquery-rails', 'jquery-ui-rails'

I am trying to use the following handler `.ajaxStop( handler )` as described here: https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/#ajaxStop-handler

I have multiple rails (remote) forms on one and the same page. When a button is clicked all the forms are submitted, all ajax calls are successfully sent, and each of the `.on("ajax:success")` events is triggered, for each of the forms. So far so good. The problem is I want to execute some JS code once ALL the ajax calls are already completed.

I tried the following as described on the jquery docs:

```
$( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
    console.log("test1");
});
```

Also tried this one, as I found this event name on Rails docs page https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#rails-ujs-event-handlers :

```
$(function() {
  $( document ).on("ajax:stopped", function() {
    console.log("test2");
  });
});
```

No luck. Nothing gets printed.

Is there a way I can do this with rails? And what is the correct event I should use?

Answer (score 0):

Didn't `.ajaxStop` work? it's jquery's callback when all ajax requests are finished. Rails `ajax:stopped` event is fired when a single ajax request is stopped.

If you want you can do something custom, you can listen to `ajax:beforeSend` events and increment a global counter of currently active ajax requests and to `ajax:complete` event to decrement that counter. After you decrement the counter check if == 0 to run your code. But that will only count rails generated ajax requests, you should be hable to use jQuery's method that's counts all jquery's ajax requests.

Comment: At least I wasn't able to make `.ajaxStop` work. Thank you for the suggestion for the custom approach. It's similar to what I am doing now, counting this particular form events, and decrementing on success/error, but it's ugly, so I'd rather use a standard event if there is a way to do this.